# How can I create a firefox extension that closes tabs without history when pressing back (mouse 4)

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have been trying to create an extension to add this functionality to Firefox.

It seems as if the "mousedown" event listener doesn't get triggered for mouse 4 & 5 on firefox so I can't use that.

Does anyone else have any ideas on how I could do this? The tabs API doesn't seem to have any listeners I could use, and even so they probably wouldn't fire if there was nowhere to go to.

My only other idea would be to add an extra item to the start of a tabs history upon creating it, but I don't think I can access that.

I tried using a "mousedown" listener, but that doesn't fire for mouse 4 & 5.